# Toggle button UI with rails button_to asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to get the button to toggle text and class asynchronously with Rails 4.  My code works fine when the page is just re rendered, but I want to be able to toggle the UI asynchronously.  Currently, I need to double click my button to get it to work correctly.

I think the problem I have is when there is more than one button_to element on the page because I want to have a list of them.  I am trying to locate the target element, but I don't know how to get it from the ajax XMLHttpRequest.

```
_interested_button.html.erb



 <% if interested? locals[:question] %>
        <%= button_to "Interested", toggle_interest_path, remote: true, params: {question: locals[:question][:id]}, class: 'btn btn-success interested_button' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= button_to "Show Interest", toggle_interest_path, remote: true, params: {question: locals[:question][:id]}, class: 'btn btn-default interested_button', id: 'interested_button' %>
    <% end %>

interest_box.js.erb

    $(function(){
        $('.interested_button').mousedown(function() {
            var newVal = ($(this).val() === "Interested") ? "Show Interest" : "Interested";
            $(this).val(newVal);
            $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-success');
    });
});

question_interest_controller.rb

class QuestionInterestController < ApplicationController

    # handle the show interest button
    def interest_box

        @question_interest = QuestionInterest.find_by(expert: current_user.id, question: params[:question])

        # Toggle between creating a new question interest and destroying the interest
        if @question_interest
            @question_interest.destroy
        else
            @question_interest = QuestionInterest.new(expert: current_user.id, question: params[:question])
            @question_interest.save
        end

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

end


views/question/index.html.erb

    <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Listing Questions</h1></div>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><%= link_to question.title, question %></h3>
        <% if expert? %>
          <!-- Toggle between interested and not interested with ajax :) -->
          <%= render 'interested_button', locals: {question: question} %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body question-body">
            <%= question.body.html_safe %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need mousedown callback in this case, `click` is the default event for link activation. Just put content directly in your `js.erb` file

```
var $button = $('.interested_button')
var newVal = ($button.val() === "Interested") ? "Show Interest" : "Interested";
$button.val(newVal);
$button.toggleClass('btn-default btn-success');
```

Good luck.

Comment: I think this is a better approach, but now if I have a list of button_to objects it changes both of them on the page.  Is there a way to only change the target one from the XMLHttprequest?

Comment: I figured it out.  I ended up using an ID not a class for my button, and then I used your technique.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#app/views/interests/interest_box.js.erb
$(document).on("click", ".interested_button", function() {
     var newVal = ($(this).val() === "Interested") ? "Show Interest" : "Interested";
     $(this).val(newVal);
     $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-success');
});
```

--

Honestly, this is improper use of `format.js` (it's meant to give you the ability to call request-based functionality); you'd be better putting the above into your asset pipeline:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".interested_button", function() {
     var newVal = ($(this).val() === "Interested") ? "Show Interest" : "Interested";
     $(this).val(newVal);
     $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-success');
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately gives me the same result as what I had before.